# sum of different records in datatables

Tags: php, datatables

i have created a table by using datatables plugin in ajax jquery and php.
there is a column of status which shows publish,unpublish....i want to show total number of records,total published and total unpublished...can i do this?

here is what i tried

```
var oTable = $('#listings_row').dataTable( {
"iDisplayLength": 25,
             "iDisplayStart": 0,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "sAjaxSource": "ajax_files/server_processing_rentals.php",
                "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {  return nRow;
}
            } );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SUM` function in queries for the (I'm assuming) SQL database.

Comment: i want to get it from datatable instead to send request to server and and get it.....